# How can I unpivot multiple columns and exclude values from either column?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, unpivot

I have a table that contains an `id` and two products columns, `product` and `product_other`. The `product` column may have a valid product name, the word "other", or be blank, as it comes from the source. The `product_other` will be expected to have a valid product name if `product` is "other", and otherwise may be blank or contain a valid product name randomly.
I need to pull all valid product names into a single column and exclude the blanks and "other" entries. I've tried two methods so far, the `UNION` method is the below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM
(
    SELECT id
        , COALESCE(NULLIF(NULLIF(product, 'other'), ''), 'UNKNOWN') AS product
    FROM myTable
    UNION
    SELECT id
        , COALESCE(NULLIF(product_other, ''), 'UNKNOWN') AS product
    FROM myTable
) k
ORDER BY id
```

This produces all rows, including 'UNKNOWN' values for `product` and valid product names for `product_other` for the same `id`, when it should only provide the valid name if there is one.

The other method I've used is the `CASE WHEN` method below:

```
SELECT id
    , CASE COALESCE(NULLIF(product, ''), 'UNKNOWN')
            WHEN 'other' THEN COALESCE(NULLIF(product_other, ''), 'UNKNOWN')
            ELSE COALESCE(NULLIF(product_other, ''), 'UNKNOWN')
        END AS product
FROM myTable
ORDER BY id
```

This one, however, has only produced a list of valid `product` where available or `product_other` when `product` is "other" or blank. It excludes the possibility of cases where there are valid `product` **product** and **product_other** values.

Another way to look at it is if you `SELECT id, count(*) FROM (`either query as k `) GROUP BY id`, there will be rows having count of 2 in the first case, whether one is "UNKNOWN" or not, and the second will always have only 1 row per `id`.

So, `myTable` looks like this:

```
id      product     product_other
------  ---------   ---------------
155535  OTC         COM
155536              OTC
155537  other       COM
155538
```

I want the query results to look like this:

```
id      product
------  ---------
155535  OTC
155535  COM
155536  OTC
155537  COM
155538  UNKNOWN
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    CREATE TABLE #temp (id   int ,   product  varchar(10),    product_other VARCHAR(10))


    INSERT INTO #temp 
    VALUES(155535,'OTC','COM'),
    (155536, '' ,'OTC'),
    (155537,'other','COM'),
    (155538,'','') 

SELECT id
    , CASE  WHEN  COALESCE(NULLIF(product, ''),NULLIF(product_other, ''))  = 'other' AND NULLIF(product_other, '') IS NOT NULL  THEN product_other
           WHEN   COALESCE(NULLIF(product, ''),NULLIF(product_other, '')) IS NULL AND  NULLIF(product_other, '') IS NULL  THEN  'UNKNOWN' 
           ELSE  COALESCE(NULLIF(product, ''),NULLIF(product_other, '')) END  AS product 
FROM #temp
UNION
SELECT id
    ,CASE  WHEN  COALESCE(NULLIF(product_other, ''),NULLIF(product, ''))  = 'other' AND NULLIF(product, '') IS NOT NULL  THEN product_other
           WHEN   COALESCE(NULLIF(product_other, ''),NULLIF(product, '')) IS NULL AND  NULLIF(product, '') IS NULL  THEN  'UNKNOWN' 
           ELSE  COALESCE(NULLIF(product_other, ''),NULLIF(product, '')) END  AS product 
FROM #temp;
```

And the results:
[image]

So in essence this is the logic:

```
SELECT id
    , CASE  WHEN  COALESCE(NULLIF(product, ''),NULLIF(product_other, ''))  = 'other' AND NULLIF(product_other, '') IS NOT NULL  THEN product_other
           WHEN   COALESCE(NULLIF(product, ''),NULLIF(product_other, '')) IS NULL AND  NULLIF(product_other, '') IS NULL  THEN  'UNKNOWN' 
           ELSE  COALESCE(NULLIF(product, ''),NULLIF(product_other, '')) END  AS product 
FROM myTable
UNION
SELECT id
    ,CASE  WHEN  COALESCE(NULLIF(product_other, ''),NULLIF(product, ''))  = 'other' AND NULLIF(product, '') IS NOT NULL  THEN product_other
           WHEN   COALESCE(NULLIF(product_other, ''),NULLIF(product, '')) IS NULL AND  NULLIF(product, '') IS NULL  THEN  'UNKNOWN' 
           ELSE  COALESCE(NULLIF(product_other, ''),NULLIF(product, '')) END  AS product 
FROM myTable;
```

Comment: With a few small changes, this works perfectly for my situation. Sometimes handling each case with large streams of code makes more sense than unpivoting data out.

Comment: Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
UNPIVOT(product_name FOR product_type IN (product, product_other)) u
WHERE
    u.product_name NOT IN ('', 'other');
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fed022/1/0)

Comment: This one removes entries like 155538 that only have a blank, but they need to be transformed to 'UNKNOWN'. Also, the SQLFiddle seems broken to me, but it could just be this computer's architecture blocking it from fully loading.